# NGINX permissions issue - HTTP error 409 when trying PUT in Postman

Tags: nginx, permissions, centos7, put, webdav

I've inherited this server, so I don't have a whole lot of experience with NGINX. But before I start changing things, and messing stuff up, I wanted to see if I could find some help here.

Server shows the homepage, and these directories are accessible from there. GET method works. POST is not setup in the web-dav directive, but I get 403 when trying it. I've checked access.log and all I'm seeing are the GET queries. error.log shows the following, however...

> 2020/08/27 13:43:12 [crit] 31561#0: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/tmp/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied), client: myClient.CPE, server: server.CPE, request: "PUT /Tech_Support_Files/2020-08-27T13:43:10_224806691313312_TSI.tar.gz.aes HTTP/1.1", host: "server.CPE"
> 2020/08/27 13:44:12 [crit] 31561#0: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/tmp/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied), client: myClient.CPE, server: server.CPE, request: "PUT /Tech_Support_Files/2020-08-27T13:43:10_224806691313312_TSI.tar.gz.aes HTTP/1.1", host: "server.CPE"
> 2020/08/27 13:45:13 [crit] 31561#0: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/tmp/0000000003" failed (13: Permission denied), client: myClient.CPE, server: server.CPE, request: "PUT /Tech_Support_Files/2020-08-27T13:43:10_224806691313312_TSI.tar.gz.aes HTTP/1.1", host: "server.CPE"

So it appears that there's a permissions issue here, but I'm apparently not finding where it's originating from. Here's my ls -l on the directory it's trying to negotiate with, which looks right to me...

```
/usr/share/nginx/html
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 3650 Oct  3  2019 404.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx 3693 Oct  3  2019 50x.html
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx   20 Apr 13 14:57 en-US -> ../../doc/HTML/en-US
drwxr-xr-x. 2 nginx nginx   27 Apr 13 14:57 icons
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx   18 Apr 13 14:57 img -> ../../doc/HTML/img
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx   25 Apr 13 14:57 index.html -> ../../doc/HTML/index.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 nginx nginx  368 Oct  3  2019 nginx-logo.png
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 nginx nginx   14 Apr 13 14:57 poweredby.png -> nginx-logo.png
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nginx nginx   22 Aug 21 16:59 Tech_Support_Files
drwxrwxr-x. 2 nginx nginx    6 Aug 25 18:48 tmp
```

Any insight into making this work is very much appreciated. Here's the current .conf file...

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   75;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

 server {
     listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
     listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
     server_name  CPE_Uploads;
     root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

     include /etc/nginx/self-signed.conf;
     include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

     add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=7200";
     add_header "allow: GET, PUT, HEAD, PURGE, DELETE, PATCH" always;
  
     location / {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
     auth_basic "Restricted Site.";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/Tech_Support_Files;
     client_body_temp_path /usr/share/nginx/html/tmp/;
     client_body_buffer_size 1M;
     client_max_body_size 8M;
     dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
     create_full_put_path on;
     dav_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;
     autoindex on;
     }

     error_page 404 /404.html;
         location = /40x.html {
     }

     error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
         location = /50x.html {
     }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by moving everything inside of the nginx user home directory.